# why `componentWillReceiveProps` is not necessary in React's "Lifting state up" example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a web page using React, and have some questions about the ["Lifting Stat Up"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) example (and I paste the link for complete code of it [here](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/WZpxpz?editors=0010) for quick reference), which is inconsistent with what I encountered in my own project.

My question is about this part:

```
    <TemperatureInput
      scale="c"
      temperature={celsius}
      onTemperatureChange={this.handleCelsiusChange} />
```

while user input new values, the `celsius` will be re-calculated (triggered by a callback function in `TemperatureInput` which calls `handleCelsiusChange`, and then `render` is triggered), and passed as one of `props` to `TemperatureInput`. But inside the definition of `TemperatureInput`, why `componentWillReceiveProps` is not defined? In my practice, if the `props` is assigned in constructor only, it will not be updated automatically if value changed. As the document said, it will not create a new element but just update the existing one for performance. If there is no new instance is created, the constructor would not be invoked, so the `this.props` will not be updated without a `componentWillReceiveProps` function.

All these above is consistent to my practice, but not to the example. Why `componentWillReceiveProps` is not required in the example to make `this.props` updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `constructor` in this case is not doing anything special with the `props`, it is just calling the `React.Component` constructor with `super()` which is what it would do anyway. If it was setting some state from props for example, then you would need a `componentWillReceiveProps`, as you would need to update the state when the props change.

When the component gets new props, the constructor is not invoked again, as it is already an instance, instead react updates the props on the component instance, and calls the `render()` again, so the props in `render()` will be the updated props. If you had a `componentWillReceiveProps` defined, it will be called before the call to `render()`;

Comment: Great! You explanation answers exactly what confused me. I made some experiment on my own code based on such understanding and the code works as expected. Thank you for the quick and accurate answer.